# Performance issue with long running computation .net core - Separate thread pool

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Consider a .Net Core 3.1 API with the following endpoints

1. GET : /computation - Performs a CPU intensive computation task
2. GET : /livecheck

High Load on /computation endpoint : 
When there is high load on the '/computation' endpoint, 300 requests per second, other endpoints slow down as all threads are used up.

During the high load calling the '/livecheck' endpoint will return a request in 5-10 seconds, which is too much.

This is a problem, because if the '/livecheck' endpoint does not respond on time, the app is killed.(AWS ECS, kills the container when livecheck takes more than 5 seconds)

Is it possible to ensure '/livecheck' endpoint still returns data, by running the '/computation' endpoint on a separate thread pool. So that it does not use up all worker threads and they are available for other endpoints?

Note :

- '/computation' has to be returned as a part of the same request,
  don't want to queue it to background task.

Any other solutions also welcome .

Comment: Are you making use of async/await within your computation endpoint? This could help prevent your problem.

Comment: Computation is a Cpu intensive operation, and by nature synchronous. There is no way to do a  "await  (1 + 1 )".   Also doing this await Task.Run(() => DoComputation()), will result in another worker thread being pulled to to the work, which does not help.

Comment: This probably sound stupid, but: If you know, your livecheck endpoint answers within, lets say 10 seconds. Can't you just configure ECS to wait longer than 5 seconds for the answer before killing the app? Or does it fluctuate to even more than that?

Comment: Yeah. That is a quick-fix. But company wide standard is try 2 times - in a 30 second gap. Response within 5 sec .Else fail it. Cant change that policy. Also it does fluctuate in higher load.

Comment: If your computation is sync, there is no way they could be interrupted. You have constant number of CPU cores, so increasing thread count wouldn't solve the issue. If you have too many threads, it [degrades performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). I would still yield thread back whenever it is possible in the computation using for example [`Task.Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the 'cpu intensive computation' is offloaded to another app and not done in the same app as the live check. An async message can be sent to trigger the computation processing to start and the app could subscribe to a finished or failed event from the processing app. That way heavy processing would not impact the response time of the web api.

Better than that, you can dockerize the apps.

Comment: That is not a option, as mentioned on the question Note: . And yes, its dockerised so scaling horizontally is not a issue. But the container gets killed by ECS cause livecheck does not respond in 5 sec.

Comment: so the requirement is to make the caller wait for the heavy computation to finish before returning the response ?

Comment: Yes. The response returns within 1000 ms in most cases. But when a huge load is put on the service, 300,400 RPS, the other endpoint stops responding

Answer (score 0):

*To extend my comments under question*

I still recommend you to follow the [best practices to avoid blocking calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1#avoid-blocking-calls).

But for now, let's assume you *really* cannot, then you should at least offload *computation* from thread whenever it suits to give processor time to *livecheck*.

Consider this example:

```
void Computation()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }   
}

void LiveCheck()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm alive.");
}

async Task Main()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    // Create 1000 blocking compuations to simulate busy thread pool
    // or thread pool starvation
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(Computation));       
    }

    // Simulate 3 seconds after thread pool is busy, execute livecheck
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    await Task.Run(LiveCheck);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"LiveCheck completed in {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds");

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

In most cases, the return result on my machine is like:

```
LiveCheck completed in 31.2030817 seconds
```

If offload *computation* from thread:

```
async Task Computation()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);

        // Yield thread every 50ms
        if ((i % 50) == 0)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
        }
    }   
}
```

Output usually is:

```
LiveCheck completed in 2.4753268 seconds
```

The **trade-off** here is a single run of computation will be slower than sync version.